# Any way to recharge the JoyCons while in the JoyCon Grip?

Tags: nintendo-switch

My SO has been playing Breath of the Wild all day, but now the Joycons are low in battery. She wants to still play on the TV, but as of now, the only way to charge the Joycons seems to be when they are embedded in the Switch screen.

So is there any way to charge the Joycons without them being in the Switch screen? Any way to charge them while they are in the grip?

Comment: http://www.polygon.com/2017/1/13/14269692/nintendo-switch-controller-charger < Might that help

Comment: Well that is dumb. At least i have a pro controller that can do the same thing. Mind submitting a quick resume of the article so I can accept as answer?

Comment: Alright ;) Give me a couple minutes though.

Comment: Note that the official plural form of one Joy-Con is many Joy-Con.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer can be found [here](http://www.polygon.com/2017/1/13/14269692/nintendo-switch-controller-charger) stating that:

> If the Joy-Con are removed from the Switch, they can be charged with the Charging Grip. That also has a USB-C connection, and plugging the cable into the Grip, which is sold separately for $29.99, will charge those controllers up.

Additional information is also found there.

Please Notice: I do not own a nintendo switch, I only beleive that the above states the answer :) .

Confirmation:

[Cad97](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/167682/cad97) confirms that this is the answer but that

> the charging grip does not have a battery and thus must be plugged in to charge the JoyCon

Full comment is found below. :D

Comment: I have access to a Switch, and can confirm. Note also that the charging grip _does not_ have a battery and thus must be plugged in to charge the JoyCon.

Comment: Thanks for the information I'll add it the above answer with your name. :)

Comment: @cad I'm curious, do you know if the charging grip plugs into one of the USB ports on the side of the dock or directly into an outlet?

Comment: @Kareen The charging grip plugs into USB-C, and comes with a USB-A (standard USB) to USB-C cable.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Charging Grip's cable is only a couple feet long, thus making it inconvenient to charge and play unless you're close to the dock.